# get a field value in model, dictionary style

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to get the value of a field in a model, by passing the field name as string to a function, as it's done with a python dictionary `dict.get(key)`, to do that I defined a function inside the model like:

```
def get(self, key):
    key = key.replace('_', '.')
    return self.__dict__.get('_prefetch').get(key)
```

my question is, is there a predefined function in odoo models that can do that, if not, how can I do that in a more pythonic way ?
Thank's in advance.

Comment: You can use `recordset['field_name']`. Why do you need this behaviour (just curious)?

Comment: in a for loop, I look for all many2one fileds in a model and there values, when I find a name of a many2one filed name in `self._fields` , I need to get its value, so I was in need to something like that, @CZoellner thank's for your answer it actually  works, `recordset.__getitem__` works fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo's `BaseModel` class has implemented `__getitem__`<sup>1</sup> which allows usage of "named indeces": `recordset['field_name']`

From Odoo 12.0 odoo.models.BaseModel:

```py
def __getitem__(self, key):
    """ If ``key`` is an integer or a slice, return the corresponding record
        selection as an instance (attached to ``self.env``).
        Otherwise read the field ``key`` of the first record in ``self``.

        Examples::

            inst = model.search(dom)    # inst is a recordset
            r4 = inst[3]                # fourth record in inst
            rs = inst[10:20]            # subset of inst
            nm = rs['name']             # name of first record in inst
    """
    if isinstance(key, pycompat.string_types):
        # important: one must call the field's getter
        return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
    elif isinstance(key, slice):
        return self._browse(self._ids[key], self.env)
    else:
        return self._browse((self._ids[key],), self.env)
```

So on recordsets the first record's attribute will be read. Try to use it on singletons if possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> for further information on generic types [click here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-generic-types)